# How to access value in an array being returned by Parse function from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, parse-platform

I'm calling a Parse function from within my iOS app, and this is what it returns:

```
(
    "<matchCenterItem: 0x7fbc6b648620, objectId: EixWxvd0kg, localId: (null)> {\n    categoryId = 171485;\n    itemCondition = New;\n    itemLocation = US;\n    maxPrice = 200;\n    minPrice = 150;\n    parent = \"<PFUser: 0x7fbc6b6526a0, objectId: kfEHfG4FUD>\";\n    searchTerm = \"nexus 7 16gb\";\n}",
    "<matchCenterItem: 0x7fbc6b652dd0, objectId: Je1VxP7dPw, localId: (null)> {\n    categoryId = 9355;\n    itemCondition = Used;\n    itemLocation = US;\n    maxPrice = 350;\n    minPrice = 250;\n    parent = \"<PFUser: 0x7fbc6b652ca0, objectId: kfEHfG4FUD>\";\n    searchTerm = \"iphone 5 unlocked\";\n}"
)
```

The formatting is a bit strange, and one that I'm not used to. What I want to do is have each cell in my table use the respective `searchTerm` value in an array like this as its title, but I'm not sure how to refer to the value correctly.

Here's the calling of the function itself:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.mcSettingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    // Disable ability to scroll until table is MatchCenter table is done loading
    self.mcSettingsTable.scrollEnabled = NO;

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"mcSettings"
                       withParameters:@{}
                                block:^(NSArray *result, NSError *error) {

                                    if (!error) {
                                        _mcSettingsArray = result;
                                        [_mcSettingsTable reloadData];
                                        self.mcSettingsTable.scrollEnabled = YES;
                                        NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                    }
                                }];

}
```

I've tried something like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = _mcSettingsArray[indexPath.row][@"matchCenterItem"][@"searchTerm"];
```

but it crashes the app and tells me that `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `mcSettingsArray` is declared strong.  Make sure that the `numberOfRowsInSection` datasource method returns `self.mcSettingsArray.count`.  The code in cellForRowAtIndexPath should look like this:

```
PFObject *item = self.mcSettingsArray[indexPath.row];
NSString *searchTerm = item[@"searchTerm"];
cell.textLabel.text = searchTerm;
```